# Convert MYSQL query to PHP Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to get this to work for some time. I'm just stumped.  Here is the original MYSQL and then the PHP Ive been working on.

MYSQL:

```
SET @COD_PAIS = 3;
SET @F_HASTACORTE = '2012-03-31 01:00:00';

SELECT mcarteras.DES_CARTERA_CC                 AS 'Short Name of Fund'
     , mcarterasflias.DES_CARTERAFLIA           AS 'I/C'
     , msociedades.DES_SOCIEDAD_CORTO           AS 'Fund Manager Company'
     , mcarteras_clases.DES_CARTERACLASE        AS 'Class'
     , mcarteras_clasesesp.DES_CARTERACLASE_ESP AS 'Special Class'
     , dr_rentmovil_carteras.POR_RENTCARTERA    AS 'TTR year-to-date %'
     , dficha_mes.POR_REMUNERA_COBRADA          AS 'Mgmt Fee Effectively Charged'
     , dficha_mes.POR_GASTOS_TOTALESC           AS 'Total Expenses %'
     , dficha_mes.VR_CARTERA_FCORTE             AS 'Fund Size'
     , dr_rentmovil_carteras.F_HASTACORTE             AS 'Date'
  FROM mcarteras
INNER
  JOIN mcarterasflias
    ON mcarterasflias.ID_CARTERAFLIA           = mcarteras.ID_CARTERAFLIA
INNER
  JOIN msociedades
    ON msociedades.ID_SOCIEDAD                 = mcarteras.ID_SOCIEDADADM
INNER
  JOIN mcarteras_clases
    ON mcarteras_clases.ID_CARTERACLASE        = mcarteras.ID_CARTERACLASE
INNER
  JOIN mcarteras_clasesesp
    ON mcarteras_clasesesp.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = mcarteras.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP  
INNER
  JOIN dr_rentmovil_carteras
    ON dr_rentmovil_carteras.ID_CARTERA        = mcarteras.ID_CARTERA   
   AND dr_rentmovil_carteras.COD_PAIS                                       = @COD_PAIS
   AND dr_rentmovil_carteras.F_HASTACORTE                                =@F_HASTACORTE
   AND dr_rentmovil_carteras.ID_FORMATO = 1
   AND dr_rentmovil_carteras. ID_COLUMNA = 5
INNER
  JOIN dficha_mes
    ON dficha_mes.ID_CARTERA                   = mcarteras.ID_CARTERA   
   AND dficha_mes.COD_PAIS                                                  = @COD_PAIS
   AND dficha_mes.F_CORTE                                              = @F_HASTACORTE 

 WHERE mcarteras.COD_PAIS                                                   = @COD_PAIS
   AND mcarteras.ID_CARTERATIPO = 4
   AND mcarteras.ID_CARTERAFLIA IN ( 3,4 )
   AND mcarteras.IND_PUBLICACION = 1
   AND mcarteras.COD_ESTADO= 1

PHP:
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 if (!$con)
   {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("bdcarterascv2", $con);
$COD_PAIS = '3';
$F_HASTACORTE = '2012-03-31 01:00:00';

$result = mysql_query("SELECT DES_CARTERA_CC               AS 'Short Name of Fund' 
     , mcarterasflias.DES_CARTERAFLIA           AS 'I/C'
     , msociedades.DES_SOCIEDAD_CORTO           AS 'Fund Manager Company'
     , mcarteras_clases.DES_CARTERACLASE        AS 'Class'
     , mcarteras_clasesesp.DES_CARTERACLASE_ESP AS 'Special Class'
     , dr_rentmovil_carteras.POR_RENTCARTERA    AS 'TTR year-to-date %'
     , dficha_mes.POR_REMUNERA_COBRADA          AS 'Mgmt Fee Effectively Charged'
     , dficha_mes.POR_GASTOS_TOTALESC           AS 'Total Expenses %'
     , dficha_mes.VR_CARTERA_FCORTE             AS 'Fund Size'
     ,dr_rentmovil_carteras.F_HASTACORTE        AS'Date'
  FROM mcarteras 
INNER
  JOIN mcarterasflias
    ON mcarterasflias.ID_CARTERAFLIA           = mcarteras.ID_CARTERAFLIA
INNER
  JOIN msociedades
    ON msociedades.ID_SOCIEDAD                 = mcarteras.ID_SOCIEDADADM
INNER
  JOIN mcarteras_clases
    ON mcarteras_clases.ID_CARTERACLASE        = mcarteras.ID_CARTERACLASE
INNER
  JOIN mcarteras_clasesesp
    ON mcarteras_clasesesp.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = mcarteras.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP  
INNER
  JOIN dr_rentmovil_carteras
    ON dr_rentmovil_carteras.ID_CARTERA        = mcarteras.ID_CARTERA   
  AND dr_rentmovil_carteras.COD_PAIS                                       =  $COD_PAIS
   AND dr_rentmovil_carteras.F_HASTACORTE                          =      $F_HASTACORTE
   AND dr_rentmovil_carteras.ID_FORMATO = 1
   AND dr_rentmovil_carteras. ID_COLUMNA = 5
INNER
  JOIN dficha_mes
    ON dficha_mes.ID_CARTERA                   = mcarteras.ID_CARTERA   
   AND dficha_mes.COD_PAIS                                            =      $COD_PAIS
   AND dficha_mes.F_CORTE                                             =  $F_HASTACORTE 

 WHERE mcarteras.COD_PAIS                                                =  $COD_PAIS
   AND mcarteras.ID_CARTERATIPO = 4
   AND mcarteras.ID_CARTERAFLIA IN ( 3,4 )
   AND mcarteras.IND_PUBLICACION = 1
   AND mcarteras.COD_ESTADO= 1
")
or die(mysql_error());

// HTML ... Aliases from Mysql
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Short Name of Fund</th>
<th>I/C</th>
<th>Fund Manager Company</th>
<th>Class</th>
<th>Special Class</th>
<th>TTR year-to-date %</th>
<th>Mgmt Fee Effectively Charged</th>
<th>Total Expenses %</th>
<th>Fund Size</th>
<th>Date</th>
</tr>";

//<tr> specifies table row. for each <td> (table data) will specify a new column.  The     $row specifies the mysql column name (in this case using an alias)
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Short Name of Fund'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['I/C'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Fund Manager Company'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Class'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Special Class'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['TTR year-to-date %'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Mgmt Fee Effectively Charged'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Total Expenses %'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Fund Size'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Here is the current error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '01:00:00 AND dr_rentmovil_carteras.ID_FORMATO = 1 AND dr_rentmovil_carte' at line 28

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions - they're depreciated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the datetime string in quotes:

```
='$F_HASTACORTE'
```

Otherwise it is evaluating `2012-03-31 01:00:00` as a number, not a datetime.

Answer (score 1):

you probably want to put quotes around your `'$VARIABLES'`. And escape them if you didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
AND dr_rentmovil_carteras.F_HASTACORTE                          =      '$F_HASTACORTE'
```

If your variables aren't integers, you should quote them - there are a few other places where you should do that, too.

You should also look at using PDO instead of the mysql_* functions, too - if you use bound parameters, you can sidestep a lot of this sort of problem very neatly.